# Get Data from Database with Json and Display they in Client

Tags: javascript, php, json, database

codes for client:

[client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA4jk.png)

codes for php server:

[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75rIc.png)

output data for product after json_encode:

```
{"id":"13","codeProduct":"114","name":"parche","image":"assets\/img\/sho.jpeg","purchasePrice":"0","sellPrice":"0","primaryQty":"110","existQty":"47","sellQty":"0","userId":null,"created_at":"2021-01-08 15:10:00","update_at":null, }
```

output data for colors after json_encode:

```
[{"name":"green"},{"name":"yellow"}]
```

output data for sizes after json_encode:

```
[{"name":"15"},{"name":"28"}]
```

The data sent to the client is separate and is neither an array nor an object

```
var myJSON = {"id":"13","codeProduct":"114","name":"parche","image":"assets\/img\/sho.jpeg","purchasePrice":"0","sellPrice":"0","primaryQty":"110","existQty":"47","sellQty":"0","userId":null,"created_at":"2021-01-08 15:10:00","update_at":null, }[{"name":"green"},{"name":"yellow"}][{"name":"15"},{"name":"28"}];
```

Is this json_encoding wrong?

this is error for client:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.http.onreadystatechange (scripts.js:26)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js:33)
```

Comment: "The data sent to the client is separate and is neither an array nor an object" So if it is not an object then definetly the `JSON.parse` will fail

Answer (score 0):

```
var myJSON = {"id":"13","codeProduct":"114","name":"parche","image":"assets\/img\/sho.jpeg","purchasePrice":"0","sellPrice":"0","primaryQty":"110","existQty":"47","sellQty":"0","userId":null,"created_at":"2021-01-08 15:10:00","update_at":null, }[{"name":"green"},{"name":"yellow"}][{"name":"15"},{"name":"28"}];
```

this is not an valid json string, you can build an json string like this

```
   let data = {
       product_info:{"id":"13","codeProduct":"114","name":"parche","image":"assets\/img\/sho.jpeg","purchasePrice":"0","sellPrice":"0","primaryQty":"110","existQty":"47","sellQty":"0","userId":null,"created_at":"2021-01-08 15:10:00","update_at":null},
       colors:[],
       sizes:[]       
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make an array and set all result to that array and after that encode it to json

#example

json_encode(array("product"=>$product,"colors"=>$colors,"sizes"=>$sizes));

after this you will got perfect json object

Answer (score 0):

I write array:

```
$res=array($product,$colors,$sizes);
```

To make sure there is an array output,
I use foreach in php

```
  foreach ($res as $key ) {
        foreach ($key as $value ) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
```

output is :

```
13114parcheassets/img/sho.jpeg001104702021-01-08 15:10:00ArrayArrayArrayArray
```

this is not suitable for json_encode!!!